# Terraform: when would you manually change the state?

Tags: terraform

According to [the docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/index.html):

> As your Terraform usage becomes more advanced, there are some cases where you may need to modify the Terraform state.

Under what circumstances would you want to directly change terraform's state?

It seems like a very dangerous practice to do it as opposed to changing the terraform code itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in thinking that it can be dangerous to modify the state file as this could corrupt the state file or cause Terraform to do things that you don't want it to as the state file drifts from your changes to the actual state of the provider it is operating against.

However, there are times when you may want to modify the state file such as for adding resources you created outside of the Terraform state file (either being created outside of Terraform entirely or just with a different state file), using the [`terraform import` command](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/import.html) or for renaming Terraform config resources using the [`terraform state` commands](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/index.html).

For example, if you start off with defining a resource directly with something like:

```
variable "ami_name" {
  default = "ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-*"
}

variable "ami_owner" {
  default = "099720109477" # Canonical
}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = [var.ami_name]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = [var.ami_owner]
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

And then you later decide to refactor this to a module so that others can call it with something like:

```
module "instance" {
  ami_name  = "my-image-name-*"
  ami_owner = "123456789"
}
```

When you run a plan after this refactoring Terraform will tell you that it wants to remove the `aws_instance.web` resource and coincidentally create a resource with the same parameters called `module.instance.aws_instance.web`.

If you want to do this without causing an outage as Terraform destroys the old resource and replaces it with the new one then you could simply edit the state file to change the name of the resource with:

```
terraform state mv aws_instance.web module.instance.aws_instance.web
```

If you then run a plan it will show an empty change, successfully completing your refactoring without causing any impact on your deployed instance.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some situations where a provider bug may require a manual change to the terraform state as a last resort.

For example, I've used azurerm to import an existing azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine that is attached to an azurerm_windows_virtual_machine that was already in the terraform code.

The import set the virtual_machine_id to all lowercase in the state file, but referencing the existing resource in the terraform code had uppercase values.

This caused a situation where the plan wanted to replace the mssql virtual machine because of the case mismatch, which couldn't be avoided without manually editing the tfstate.

For the most part however, you should never have to manaully edit the state file, and if you do, it's probably because of a bug.